# Is it possible to host Kubernetes node from network with dynamic ip?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm

I would like to host a Kubernetes master node in AWS (or other cloud provider) and then add nodes from home to that cluster. I do however not have a static IP from my internet provider, so the question is: will this work and what happens when my IP address change?

Answer (score 2):

Here could get some info about [Master-Node communication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/master-node-communication/) in kubernetes.

For communication from Node to Mater, it will use kube-apiserver to do requests. So normally it should be work, and when your node IP is changed, node info in ETCD for your node will be update, and you could check your nodes status with command `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

But if some specific kubernetes feature may be affected, such as NodePort for Service.

Hope this could help !